# Does the distribution whose support is on $\mathbb R$ with pdf of the form $\exp[- a x^2 (1 + b x + c x^2 + \cdots) ]$ have a name?

Tags: distributions, terminology

Does the distribution whose support is on the real line with pdf of the form $\exp[- a x^2 (1 + b x + c x^2 + \cdots) ]$ have a name? What is it? Looking for an answer that is not something like 'zero dimensional field theory'.

Comment: Do you have a reference or link to some example of use? Some googling gives me nothing

Comment: This pdf is literally *any* real analytic density, once you allow for the possibility of a translation.  Thus, it's not a useful formulation or restriction beyond asserting the support of the distribution is the reals and it has an analytic density.

Comment: @whuber, +1 I agree with you're comments and there would need to be some restrictions on the parameters (I'm assuming that's what they are intended to be) $a, b, c, \dots$.